# Using the limit comparison test to study a parametric series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I want to study the following series using the limit comparison test (ONLY, I'm not interested in other tests because I want to find how much the LCT is powerful): $\sum \frac{1}{n^{5x}+1/n}$. My professor told us that one can use the LCT calculating $lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{5x}}{n^{5x}+1/n}$ to find that the given series goes like $\frac{1}{n^{5x}}$, so it is convergent for $x>1/5$ and divergent otherwise. But I'm puzzled by the way this test was applied: $lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{5x}}{n^{5x}+1/n}>0$ only if $x \geq-1/5$, so we should be able to conclude that the given series goes like $\frac{1}{n^{5x}}$ only for $x \geq-1/5$ (and thus find that the series converges for $x>1/5$ and diverges when $-1/5 \leq x \leq 1/5$. What happens when $x<-1/5$? Is it possible to deduce how the series behaves only (ONLY) using the limit comparison test?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't say, "the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{5x}+1/n}$ *goes like* the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{5x}}$," because it is not clear what this means, and their value might be very different. You should say: $\sum \frac{1}{n^{5x}+1/n}$ converges $\iff \sum \frac{1}{n^{5x}}$ converges.

When $\ x<-\frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{n} $ dominates (i.e. is largest) in the expression $\ \frac{n^{5x}}{n^{5x}+1/n},\ $ and so $\ lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{5x}}{n^{5x}+1/n}\ $ diverges and the LCT **does not apply** (i.e. you cannot use LCT here). However, since it is the $ \frac{1}{n} $ term that dominates here, we make consider applying a different LCT - $\ lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1/n}{n^{5x}+1/n}=1>0\ $ for any $\ x<-\frac{1}{5}.\quad \sum 1/n\ $ diverges, so LCT says that $\ \sum\frac{1}{n^{5x}+1/n}\ $ diverges also (for any $\ x<-\frac{1}{5}$).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test#Statement

Comment: thanks for your answer. First of all, since English is not my main language, I used the expression "goes like" meaning that the series I mentioned "do the same thing". Also, I know a form of the LCT which states that given to sequences whose terms are positive, if $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=l$, then if $l>0$ the series "do the same thing", while if $l=0$, then $\sum a_n <\sum b_n$ and we can apply the comparison test. If $l=\infty$, then $\sum b_n<\sum a_n$ and we can aplly the comparison test

Comment: In the previous comment I wrote "do the same thing" just to save space, but the meaning is the one you wrote in your answer

Comment: By the way, I would like to know wheter it is possible to solve the exercise by evaluating only $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{5x}}{n^{5x}+1/n}$, using the theorem I mentioned in the comments